# React native - Stack Screen flikering on authentication flow

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

React native Login Stack Blinks while opening the app, before showing the home page. Using react native navigation V5.
Adding the Token from server to async Storage, then on opening the app, i check for the token in Async storage, if it's not null, i'll navigate to my `AppScreens` else stay in `AuthScreens`

**AppNavigator**

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import AddUserData from '../lib/UserDetailsHelper';

//Import screens
import Login from '../Login';
import AddReferalCode from '../AddReferalCode';
import AddUserDetails from '../AddUserDetails';
import DrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigator';
import BuyCoins from '../BuyCoins';
import PriceList from '../PriceList';
//Quick Play
import QuickPlayGameList from '../QuickPlay/GameList';
import QuickplayRoom from '../QuickPlay/RoomCreationScreen';
import QuickPlayWaitingRoom from '../QuickPlay/waitingRoom';
import QuickPlayQuestions from '../QuickPlay/Questions';
import QuickPlayResult from '../QuickPlay/Result';

import RNBootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthScreens = (props) => (
  <AuthStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerTitle: false,
    }}>
    {/* Common */}
    <Stack.Screen {...props} name="Login" component={Login} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AddReferalCode" component={AddReferalCode} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Add User Details" component={AddUserDetails} />
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
);

const AppScreens = () => (
  <AppStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerTitle: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Drawer" component={DrawerNavigator} />
    <Stack.Screen name="BuyCoins" component={BuyCoins} />
    <Stack.Screen name="PriceList" component={PriceList} />
    {/* <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} /> */}
    {/* QuickPlay */}
    <Stack.Screen name="QuickPlayGameList" component={QuickPlayGameList} />
    <Stack.Screen name="QuickplayRoom" component={QuickplayRoom} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="QuickPlayWaitingRoom"
      component={QuickPlayWaitingRoom}
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="QPQuestions" component={QuickPlayQuestions} />
    <Stack.Screen name="QPResult" component={QuickPlayResult} />
  </AppStack.Navigator>
);

Routes = (props) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  console.log('Props acc token:' + props.accessToken);

  useEffect(() => {
    getToken()
      .then((token) => {
        setToken(token);
      })
      .finally(async () => {
        await RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true});
      });
  }, []);

  const getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AccessToken');
      const rating = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserRating');
      console.log('first token:' + token);
      setToken(token);
      AddUserData.addAccessToken(token);
      AddUserData.addUserRating(rating);
      return token;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return token ? <AppScreens /> : <AuthScreens />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    accessToken: state.userDetails.accessToken,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Routes);
```

The `AuthScreen` Stack blinking when opening the app.

ScreenRecoding of the issue

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12p2NtxUbfS-eFt5iGM0PAvhuJZJhUyJQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please try placing your home screen BEFORE the login screen and see the effet

```
  <AuthStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerTitle: false,
    }}>


//      >>>  PUT HOME SCREEN HERE


    {/* Common */}
    <Stack.Screen {...props} name="Login" component={Login} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AddReferalCode" component={AddReferalCode} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Add User Details" component={AddUserDetails} />
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
```

Additional information: (thanks for Thorin's discovery)

```
Try to add a Splash screen to the project, and add a small time out of say 10ms, it may be able to fix the problem.
```

Comment: Great . Have a nice day

Comment: hey mate,  But when I logout and clear my `token` the app just goes back to HomeScreen again, instead on Login Page. What to do about that.? Also when I open it for the first time it shows homeScreen instead on login or signup pages

Comment: Pls add a line to navigate to login screen after u log out

Comment: yeah, but still when the app opened for the first time it goes to `HomeScreen` instead of AuthScreens

Comment: the normal practice is to show the home, and then if user wants to login he/she clicks a button or link

Comment: Otherwise u need to add further navigate logics on the screens

Comment: HI Thorin, Just to follow-up. Have you fixed your problems ?

Comment: Hey mate, i added a Splash screen to the project, Then also i had the issue so, i added a small time out of 1ms. which seem to fix the problem for now!

Comment: Great , so the time out fixed the problem.

Comment: I have added your trick to my answer as "Additional Information" . Thanks